# How to run an .exe with arguments remotely in python?

Tags: python, remote-access, psexec

I am trying to connect a virtualbox machine through smb port and file sharing. I want to run a command in it's terminal. I tried psexec like :

```
    psexecloc ="PsExec.exe"
    remotecmd="Users\\vboxuser\\Desktop\\helloexe.exe selamlar windows"
    username = "vboxuser"
    password = "changeme"
    remotehostname = "\\\\192.168.1.8"
    args = [psexecloc, "-i", "-u", username, "-p", password, remotehostname,remotecmd]
    output = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I also tried pypsexec.client like :

```
    c = Client("192.168.1.8", username="vboxuser", password="changeme")
    c.connect()
```

They both give me access denied error, what should i do how can i give access?

Comment: Can you use psexec successfully directly from the terminal _without_ Python? It's not a Python question if the problem still happens when you take Python away. If you can show us a working shell command _and also_ show us non-working Python code, that's a lot more helpful than only seeing non-working Python code.